# WiFi camera connects to network without needing password. How?

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, wireless-access-point

I installed a ESCAM QF600 Wifi camera where I plugged the WiFi device in and pressed its reset button for 5 seconds. I then installed its Android app, idoor,  where I connected to the network specified in the Android app the WiFi access point and password.

The Wifi camera is now connected to the network and can be accessed from anywhere.

How did it password get from the Android app to the Wifi camera to allow it to connect to the network. This is probably really obvious but I can't figure it out. Is Android app listening on some local ip address? Can it do that? Is the camera?

Comment: Don't you think that, in order to get an answer, you may at least specify the product brand and model?

Comment: @Marco it's an Escam QF600 but my question is a general question: how can a WiFi device connect to a WiFi network by putting the pasword into a separate Android app.

Comment: What's the name of the app u've been using to setup the cam?

Comment: Tha app is called idoor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've attached several (non-camera) devices like this, such as the Amazon Dash Button.  The Dash creates its own Wifi AP temporarily, and the Android connects to it and updates the configuration. The Dash then shuts down its Wifi AP and connects to the designated network, and the Android also switches back to its normal Wifi configuration and validates that the Dash has connected.

I strongly suspect your camera works similarly.

Comment: Thanks - so the app can connect to a different access point as the phone with a hard coded name and password? Apps are allows to do this?

Comment: The temp ap will probably have no pass. The same thing may happen via Bluetooth too

Comment: Yeah its normally an unprotected AP. Apps can do this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically.

Comment: This is particularly interesting g as I have a WiFi proxy product idea  using CHiP $9 computer that could use this although I probably will not go beyond PoC. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary WiFi AP is one answer to this, but another solution that is sometimes used is "Smart Config".  This was a technology developed by Texas Instruments where there is no temporary AP set up, and the mobile device used for configuration does not need to disconnect from your home AP. Other wifi modules such as ESP8266 have also started using their own implementation.

In a nutshell, the mobile device used for configuration sends specially crafted packets to your normal AP which the AP ignores, but encoded in the length of those packets is the SSID and password. The new device listens for these crafted packet lengths, and while it has no way to decrypt the actual data in the packets, it can still collect all the data it needs to connect itself.

A great (if outdated) writeup with technical details on the implementation is [here](http://depletionregion.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/cc3000-smart-config-transmitting-ssid.html) if you are interested. Initial implementations were definitely insecure (yes, you were basically transmitting your wifi password in the clear), but I think that implementations in the past few years have encrypted the password as well, requiring a private key embedded in the hardware to decrypt.

Comment: That sounds like an awesome implementation of an intentional cover-channel attack.